# Convert List<string> to ArrayList

Tags: c#, .net, list, arraylist

Who knows the easiest way to convert a `List` of strings to an `ArrayList`?

I tried setting `(ArrayList)` before the code but this doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Sure:

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(list);
```

That works because `List<T>` implements `ICollection`.

However, I'd strongly advise you to *avoid* `ArrayList` (and other non-generic collections) if at all possible. Can you refactor whatever code wants an `ArrayList` to use a generic collection instead?

Comment: I have a similar use case...can you please explain why you recommend avoid ArrayList and other non-generic collections?

Comment: @AJW: Because they aren't safe at compile-time - they don't stop you from putting the "wrong" kind of thing in (compared with what you expect) and you need to cast everything coming out of them.

Comment: I understand.  Almost every tutorial and codelabs that I've reviewed dealing with a RecyclerView list and its adapter show the use of an ArrayList.  Yet the Room database DAOs seem to use List exclusively to return data from for example a SQLite database.  So your recommendation would be to use a List in the RecyclerView and its adapter, since the DAO is returning a List?

Comment: @AJW: I've never even heard of `RecyclerView` before that comment (that I remember, anyway) I'm afraid.

Comment: @AJW: If this is Android, bear in mind that there's a big difference between `ArrayList` in Java (which is generic) and `ArrayList` in .NET (which isn't).

Comment: Ah, yes I am working in Android.  What is the easiest way to tell if a method is generic or non-generic?

Comment: @AJW: `ArrayList` is a class, not a method. Basically, read the documentation - if it's something like `ArrayList<T>` then it's generic; if it's just `ArrayList` then it's not. That goes for both C# and Java, but there are differences in terms of whether it's valid to use the "raw type" or not (which is only a concept in Java).

Comment: @AJW: And if you're not using C#, this entire question is irrelevant to you :)

Comment: Apologies, I'm an Android newbie.  And yes I thought the question was about Android's ArrayList.

Comment: I'm working with remoting and serializable, this doesn't support generics

Answer (score 9):

ArrayList has a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83h9yskw.aspx) which accepts an `ICollection`. Since [`List<T>` implements `ICollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), the following should work:

```
var myArrayList = new ArrayList(myList);
```